# Rails and React, loading react-typeahead component with require

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, requirejs, reactjs

I have React working with rails using the `react-rails` gem.  It is rendering the `HelloMessage` component from the react front page just fine.

I then used Bower to install 'react-typeahead' ([react-typeahead github](https://github.com/fmoo/react-typeahead))

```
var Typeahead = require('react-typeahead').Typeahead;
```

The problem is that `require` is not defined.  I've looked into requirejs-rails and browserify-rails, but the first requires you to stop using sprockets, and I was unable to get the second working.

I'm new to this, how should I be getting require to work with this the 'react-typeahead' component?

Currently with browserify I am getting:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-typeahead' from '/Users/xxx/code/xxx/app/assets/javascripts'
    at /Users/xxx/code/xxx/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
```

Even though I installed it in that directory with bower.  I've double checked and it matches the path.

Answer (score 0):

In your require statement, you need to require the exact path of the library you're looking to import if it's not in the same folder, for example:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-typeahead' from '/Users/xxx/code/xxx/app/assets/javascripts'
at /Users/xxx/code/xxx/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
```

Notice how it's looking in app/assets/javascripts, point it towards your node_modules folder.